# Kivy Python: Pass variable and instance from class(screen) to another class(screen)

Tags: python, kivy, instance, screen, self

When I pass from one Screen to the next screen in my Python and Kivy App, I need to bring some variables or the previous instance "Self".
For example, in my code, I use the FirstLayout(Screen) Info variable in Kivy file and it is OK.
After that, I need to use the same variable Info in LoginId(Screen) Class.
I can't because I can't pas the previous instance in the new class. And I need the previous instance "Self" to keep the communication betwwen .py and .kv

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty


class FirstLayout(Screen):
    Info = ListProperty([])
    def check(self):
        L = ['aa', 12]
        self.manager.get_screen('First').Info = L

class LoginId(Screen):
    #I need to obtain the Info Variable, I can't use FirstLayou.Info, 
    #I can't use FirstLayoutmanager.get_screen('First').Info
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        manager = ScreenManager()
        manager.add_widget(FirstLayout(name='First'))
        manager.add_widget(LoginId(name='Login'))

        return manager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Answer (score 0):

My fault is I call the Info Value in '''def **init**(self, **kwargs):'''
However I need to call the Info Value in:
''' def on_enter(self, *largs):
print(self.manager.get_screen('First').Info[6])'''